# Explicit integral could not be found

Tags: matlab, integral, numerical-integration

I am getting a well-known error of "Explicit integral could not be found" if I try to evaluate following integral

```
syms z;
funz=1./(1+exp((z*z-0.5)/0.1));
Integ2=int(funz,z,0,inf)
```

I get the warning:

```
Warning: Explicit integral could not be found.        
Integ2 =   
int(1/(exp(10*z^2 - 5) + 1), z == 0..Inf)
```

Mathematica evaluates this integral to `0.693`.

I have tried replacing lower integration limit to some small finite number  (0.001) but that doesn't help. 
Please help in identifying the fix for this problem.
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks a lot !

Comment: Looks like you numerically evaluated the integral in Mathematica but you're using a symbolic technique in Matlab.

Comment: At least in R2013a, `int` isn't going to work. Mathematica's `Integrate` does return a closed form solution in terms of `PolyLog` if you specify your numbers as rationals rather than decimals: `-(1/2) Sqrt[\[Pi]/10] PolyLog[1/2, -E^5]`. Feel free to [report this to The MathWorks](http://www.mathworks.com/support/servicerequests/create.html). Matlab's MuPAD has a [`polylog`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/polylog.html) function, but I'm not sure how far back it goes. Otherwise, you'll have to use numerical methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [variable-precision arithmetic](http://www.mathworks.se/help/symbolic/vpa.html), `vpa`:

```
syms z; 
funz=1./(1+exp((z*z-0.5)/0.1));

Integ2=int(funz,z,0,inf)
Warning: Explicit integral could not be found. 

Integ2 =
int(1/(exp(10*z^2 - 5) + 1), z = 0..Inf)

vpa(Integ2,5)  % 5 is the number of significant digits
ans =     
0.69305
```

See the last example in the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.se/help/symbolic/int.html), "Approximate Definite Integrals".
Quote:

> If int cannot compute a closed form of a definite integral, try
>   approximating that integral numerically using vpa.

Comment: Wow. +1. I did not know about that. Calling `double` directly works too. The help doesn't mention it at all – at least not in R2013a. I'm used to such warnings being the result of something that `int` can't handle. I wonder what sort of quadrature it's using under the hood to perform the numeric approximation?