# Calculating a definite integral results in a really complex numerical expression instead of a numerical value

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I am trying to calculate the percentage of sun radiation that is in the visible spectrum.

My code is:

```
h=6.626e-34;  %planck constant
c=3e8;        %speed of light
k=1.38066e-23; %boltzman constant
T1=5777;       %temperature in surface of sun  

syms f

J1 =(2*pi*h/(c^2))*((f^3)/(exp((h*f)/(k*T1))-1)); %planck radiation law

hold on;
ezplot(J1,[0,1.5e15])
a=int(J1,f,0,inf)  %total energy radiated
b=int(J1,f,4e14,8e14) %energy between 400-800Thz (visible radiation spectrum)
Vp = (b/a)*100  %percentage of visible/total radiation
```

While the plot is exactly as it was expected to be, meaning i haven't totally messed it up, the result of the integrals is like this:

```
Vp = -1888568826285205004703258735621345426367059580820393216707788800000000000*((73396718487075910602267519716779133887030184268951416015625*log(1 - exp(23642358029674224853515625/7114894705749824515342336)))/205953985278202888163058116890711980917418253877248 - (73396718487075910602267519716779133887030184268951416015625*log(1 - exp(23642358029674224853515625/3557447352874912257671168)))/25744248159775361020382264611338997614677281734656 - (2390487322005187985890576650155251369405251302897930145263671875*polylog(2, exp(23642358029674224853515625/3557447352874912257671168)))/1857466834100924357302864708366291649120175241251782656 + (25952248522181378144831874533777514511468878135769288445192954296875*polylog(3, exp(23642358029674224853515625/3557447352874912257671168)))/67008813354583054015095330308295397033299967000474002915328 - (110058495767576691259417256590823904271799518678985866399923893187011219092083*polylog(4, exp(23642358029674224853515625/3557447352874912257671168)))/1888568826285205004703258735621345426367059580820393216707788800000000 + (2390487322005187985890576650155251369405251302897930145263671875*polylog(2, exp(23642358029674224853515625/7114894705749824515342336)))/7429867336403697429211458833465166596480700965007130624 - (25952248522181378144831874533777514511468878135769288445192954296875*polylog(3, exp(23642358029674224853515625/7114894705749824515342336)))/134017626709166108030190660616590794066599934000948005830656 + (110058495767576691259417256590823904271799518678985866399923893187011219092083*polylog(4, exp(23642358029674224853515625/7114894705749824515342336)))/1888568826285205004703258735621345426367059580820393216707788800000000 + 101409666798338314597227594049400067888200283050537109375/22835963083295358096932575511191922182123945984))/(12228721751952965695490806287869322696866613186553985155547099243001246565787*pi^4)
```

It is just a numerical expression (does not contain any constants) but i was expecting (and I am trying to find) a single value.

Any ideas how to overcome this?
Thanks in advance

```
double(Vp)
```

returns 44.3072 which is exactly what I was looking for while

```
vpa(Vp)
```

returns 44.307238264260285485868531074049 + 1.5008384323384489567473242679822e-35*i which is overcomed by

```
norm(vpa(Vp))
```

giving the same result as double(Vp)

However when i added a few more lines of code:

```
d=int(J1,f,0,4e14);  %infrared energy
e=int(J1,f,8e14,inf); %ultraviolet energy
Ir = (d/a)*100;  %percentage of infrared radiation
Uv = (e/a)*100;  %percentage of ultraviolet radiation
```

double(Ir) gives this error:

```
Error using mupadmex
Error in MuPAD command: DOUBLE cannot convert the input expression into a  double array.

If the input expression contains a symbolic variable, use the VPA function  instead.

Error in sym/double (line 514)
    Xstr = mupadmex('symobj::double', S.s, 0);

Error in symplanckradlaw (line 21)
Infrared=double(Ir)
```

While vpa(Ir) and even norm(vpa(Ir)) are given complicated complex numerical expressions like this

```
(abs(7.3340024900713941224341547032249e-56*limit((652255981594442743874468745505068648842285814001516463259648*f^2*polylog(2, exp((3873563939581825*f)/466281739436020499437475332096)))/15004497594028668398955870330625 - (608270107310811468411217054651916403272252179121058584901915330886243977872955782952124416*f*polylog(3, exp((3873563939581825*f)/466281739436020499437475332096)))/58120880811771703455030054556291506586990890625 - f^4/4 + (466281739436020499437475332096*f^3*log(1 - exp((3873563939581825*f)/466281739436020499437475332096)))/3873563939581825 + (283625243683820020974472587101002022201492492463545426687503953676410023626686775978867575742611811818507908158310055936*polylog(4, exp((3873563939581825*f)/466281739436020499437475332096)))/225134948049212098682315198853176286979563186266469146812890625, f == 0, Right) - 146.24549829953781858190522266202 - 2.501397387230748261245540446637e-36*i)^2)^(1/2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason Matlab while was able to evaluate the limits in this integral

```
a=int(J1,f,0,inf)
```

it had problems evaluating limit to 0 in this integral

```
d=int(J1,f,0,4e14);
```

and limit to infinite in this integral

```
e=int(J1,f,8e14,inf);
```

I worked around this by putting instead of 0 a very low value (1e-45) and instead of infinite a very large one (1e22).
I got very good results for my purposes but I still find it really strange that matlab can evaluate the limits in one case but cannot evaluate the same limits in another case.

Answer (score 3):

You can convert it to a double using, well: [`double`](https://se.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/double.html):

```
Vp_double = double(Vp)
```

You can also use [`vpa`](https://se.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/vpa.html) if you want to choose the precision:

```
Vp_vpa = vpa(Vp)
```

---

The reason why you get that immensely long expression is because MATLAB managed to find a "closed form definite integral". I.e. MATLAB managed to find an expression that accurately calculate the integral with no rounding errors. This is not always possible, and you'll get an error:

> Warning: Explicit integral could not be found.

If that happens then you should try the approach given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20083274/2338750).

Comment: I just edited the question because not enough room in comments. Please take a look.